# Qt: QTabWidget not responding to clicks

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am creating a Qt GUI with C++.

My intention is to prompt the user when the tab bar is double clicked or single clicked. This works when I create the GUI using **Qt Creator**; however, when I `qmake` and run with **XCode**, the GUI does not respond to either single or double clicks.

I am using the signals `tabBarDoubleClicked(int)` and `tabBarClicked(int)` from QTabWidget.

*Why do I experience different behavior when building with **Qt Creator** as opposed to **XCode**?*

*How can I make **XCode** recognize single and double clicks to the tabBar?*

Edit: Also, I cannot find documentation for these functions. I find that strange due to **Qt Creator** listing this as applicable signals. *Why?*

Comment: The problem is that Qt Creator is using Qt version > 5 while XCode was using Qt version < 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option is - as you write in the comment -, that you are using different Qt versions.

Another option in general is that people invoke qmake slightly different, e.g. from a different folder than QtCreator, etc.

Comment: QMAKESPEC was set to Qt 4.8 when invoked from the terminal. Qt Creator was using Qt 5.2. I'm not sure how to proceed, however. I wasn't even aware I had these two different versions. I plan to try to Qt Development in my Windows partition.